# iAd Framework Accidentally Deleted

Tags: xcode

I accidentally trashed the `iAd` framework.

I clicked "Put Back", but it won't show in my Xcode project when I try adding it. How can I get it back?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer since putting it back?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-add the framework, you have to put it back into its original folder, which is at `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

You can get to the folder by going to `Finder`, then pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (`Go to Folder...`), and then entering **/System/Library/Frameworks** in the field.

Then, drag `iAd.framework` back to its original folder, and restart Xcode.